# Magento 2 UI more than one select fields

Tags: uicomponent, adminform

I build an Admin Magento 2 form with UI form component.
I have added 3 fields of type "Select".

When I change one of the **three** they change and the rest with the same value.
Any ideas why is this happening?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">


    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">create_product_form.create_product_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">create_product_form.create_product_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Form</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="create_product_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\SampleForm\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">create_product_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="sample_fieldset">
        <settings>
            <label>Add Product</label>
        </settings>


        <field name="sku" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <label>ERP SKU (Product Code)</label>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <notice>Fill the SKU Code from the ERP Product, you want to add.</notice>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="special_price" formElement="select">
            <settings>

                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label>Special Price</label>
                <notice>The Special Price is the price after discount</notice>
                <dataScope>value</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="MainSys\StatusSync\Model\PriceFields"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
        <field name="manufacturer_price" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label>Manufacturer Price</label>
                <notice>The Manufacturer Price is the suggested price by Manufacturer</notice>
                <dataScope>value</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options class="MainSys\StatusSync\Model\PriceFields"/>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share your xml code

Comment: i added my code

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the error.
They just had the same dataScope!!
value

Comment: yes right.. thumbs up!